# what is the protected mode in php

Tags: php

I Protected works only one inherited class know ,

In this code , the protected works in third class ,

Is It true or any mistake i made in my code ,

```
<?php
class sample_visibility{

    public function my_first_public(){
        $MSG = "THIS IS MY PUBLIC FUNCTION ";
        return $MSG;
    }
    private function my_first_private(){
        $MSG = "THIS IS MY PRIVATE FUNCTION ";
        return $MSG;
    }
    protected function my_first_protected(){
        $MSG = "THIS IS MY PROTECTED FUNCTION ";
        return $MSG;
    }
}
class sample_visibilit2  extends sample_visibility{
    public function my_first_child_public(){

        $MSG = "THIS IS MY CHILD  PUBLIC FUNCTION ".$this->my_first_protected();
        return $MSG;
    }
}

class sample_visibilit3  extends sample_visibility{
    public function my_first_child_public_3(){

        $MSG = "THIS IS MY CHILD  PUBLIC FUNCTION ".$this->my_first_protected();
        return $MSG;
    }
}
$OBJ_CLASS_1 = new sample_visibility();
echo $OBJ_CLASS_1->my_first_public();

$OBJ_CLASS_3 = new sample_visibilit3();
echo $OBJ_CLASS_3->my_first_child_public_3();
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have made no mistake in your code.  Protected elements (members or functions) are accessible by children, grandchildren, (great-)*grandchildren.  Any number of inheritances is ok.  They are only "protected" from unrelated classes.

```
public - accessible anywhere
protected - derived classes only (any number of inheritances)
private - only accessible internally
```

Comment: +1 Thanks for pointing out the arbitrary depth of inheritance.

Comment: and thank you for showing me how to spell "inheritance"             /me edits answer

Comment: see i can access protected function in sample_visibility (parent class) also, So there is no diff between public and private, can u please tell diff between  public and protected

Comment: jon_darkstar's list was quite clear. Which difference you don't understand?

Comment: There is every difference between public and private.  If i may go out on a limb, I think you do not notice the difference between public and protected because you do not attempt to access protected from anywhere except sub-classes.  Add the following lines at the VERY BOTTOM of your code "echo $OBJ_CLASS_1->my_first_public();" and "echo $OBJ_CLASS_1->my_first_protected();"   See how the first works and the second doesn't

Answer (score 0):

Although your question is not very clear, your code is correct and will work.

Inside the classes `sample_visibilit2` and `sample_visibilit3` you can access `my_first_protected()`, because both classes are subclasses of `sample_visibility`.

Comment: see i can access protected function in sample_visibility (parent class) also, So there is no diff between public and private, can u please tell diff between  public and protected